# Map class to string in Scala

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework

I have a little problem regarding mapping in Play Framework under Scala.
I have a

```
case class Class1(
    role: Class2) {...}
```

Class2 is a trait,which is extended by 2 objects: Obj1 and Obj2.
I need to insert every object of Class1 in a database, which expects a String in the column for role(of type Class2). That is,I need to map Obj1 to "Obj1" and Obj2 to "Obj2". How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean you have an `object Obj1 extends Class2`? If you make it a case objects its `toString` method will return `"Obj1"`.

Comment: My Class1 has "Int,String,Class2" as type parameters. I need to insert objects of Class1 into a database that expectes as datatypes "Int, Character(255),Character(255)",so when I call the insert method, it won't work with a Class1 object as argument,it won't work,as the thrd argument is of type Class2,while it expects a Character(255).

Comment: And who wrote the insert method? I suspect there's not enough information in the question.